# Why is (f . l) not allowed and equal to (apply f l)?

Tags: scheme, racket

In scheme when defined

```
(define f (lambda (a b c d) d))

(define l (list 'a 'b 'c 'd))
```

Why it does not do argument destructuring? I mean arguments should evaluate first, why destructuring is not part of that?

```
(f . l)
```

What are reasons that this expression is not equal with following?

```
(apply f l)
```

- Edited to make it clearer, according suggestions in comments

Comment: Are you asking why scheme doesn't do argument destructuring, or why it doesn't allow the syntax which looks like a dotted pair to apply functions?

Comment: Why it does not do argument destructuring? I mean arguments should evaluate first, why destructuring is not part of that? Sorry for ambiguity.

Comment: You should edit the question to make it more clear rather than reply to the comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason is, `(f . l)` can only work if `l` is an identifier (or some other atomic literal), and not if it's a more complicated expression. Consider a function for calculating the sum-of-squares:

```
(define (sum-of-squares . nums)
  (apply + (map square nums)))
```

Here, you cannot rewrite the `(apply + (map square nums))` into `(+ . (map square nums))`, because that is equivalent (at read-time, way before evaluation happens) to `(+ map square nums)`. And `map`, `square`, and `nums` are not numbers. ;-)

Therefore, implementations *have* to supply an `apply` procedure. And once you do, there's no real point to supporting a dotted procedure-application expression that only works some of the time, when `apply` works correctly all the time.

(Many thanks to Brian Mastenbrook for explaining this to me years ago, back when I had a similar question myself.)